# Hosting two RoR applications on same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a RoR application running on a server(VM) alone. It doesn't have any domain name and we are using dedicated IP address to access the application(e.g. 192.168.1.1/app). The folder structure of this app on the server rests like /var/www/app.

My question is that can I use the same server for hosting another RoR app2 as /var/www/app2 and access it in same way 192.168.1.1/app2 ?

We have thin server running for the application and Apache for handling proxy requests.

Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the server and bind it to a different port:

```
thin start -p 81
```

then you can go to it via `192.168.1.1:81`

Comment: I have set up the thin server to run on port 3004 but the request is not going to that application, if I go via 192.168.1.1:3004, it doesn't recognize the request. How to make it recognize that the request is coming for second application on same server ?

Comment: You might also have to bind the server to an IP: `thin start -a 192.168.1.1 -p 3004`. The default bound address is `0.0.0.0` so this might do the trick.

Comment: Still not successful. It displays the following error as logged        "Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails." I have an apache server which is acting as the reverse proxy for the other thin server already running for first application